# Knockout: Why would comment tags not be working?

Tags: knockout.js

If I try this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: data.cards -->
<div>
   SHOULD SEE MULTIPLE TIMES BUT ONLY SEE ONCE
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I just get one div with no data.  If I do this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: data.cards">
   THIS IS SEEN MULTIPLE TIMES
</div>
```

It works as expected - multiple divs with data.  Why would the first approach not work?  It's especially odd because in another page, this structure works fine.

Here's what I see in the watch console in chrome:

[image]

And here's the vm I'm returning to the view:

```
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    data: observableData,
    refresh: refresh,
};
```

The only thing I change is moving the foreach from the div to a comment and it stops working.

UPDATE: If I remove the `<!-- /ko -->` closing tag, I don't get an error, when I believe I should be getting `Cannot find closing comment tag to match`.  The browser isn't recognizing the comment tag at all :/

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: The posted code should work. You have something else in your actual code which causes your problem. Are you get any errors a console? Can you reproduce the issue? Maybe in a JSFiddle?

Comment: no, and I can access data.cards in both cases via the watch console in chrome

Comment: @nemesv I tried on fiddle but it's working as expected :/

Comment: check the html coming back from your server.  could something be stripping your comments before it gets to the browser so knockout doesn't see them?

Comment: @user2359560 I checked the browser and the comments weren't showing up.  I wrapped the whole thing in a div and all of the sudden they started registering.  So weird.

Comment: If it is IE, escape the foreach like this: <!-- ko 'foreach': data.cards -->

Comment: So I can try to replicate the issue, which browser is WebDriver using?

Comment: what is 'observableData'? vm.data.cards should be a function when in console. vm.data.cards() would return the array

Comment: wouldn't <!-- ko foreach: cards --> work too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue with our project because we compress the response and remove comments. One workaround in order to avoid using a `<div>` or `<span>` for your foreach is to define your own `<ko>` element. If you do this, you will need to include the following script for IE8 and lower support:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
 <script> 
    document.createElement("ko");
 </script>
<![endif]-->
```